# Spring AOP- Logging: Logs are not getting printed

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-aop

I am new to Spring-AOP and trying to use it in my project. I have created a class implementing `MethodBeforeAdvice` :

```
public class LogBeforeCallAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice#before(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public void before(Method arg0, Object[] arg1, Object arg2)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("**CALLING METHOD - " + arg0.getName() + " IN BEFORE CALLING ADVICE**");

    }

}
```

These are the entries my application-context.xml file:

```
<bean id="proxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">  
    <property name="target" ref="logMethods"></property>  
    <property name="interceptorNames">  
        <list>  
        <value>beforeCall</value>  
    </list>  
    </property>  
</bean>
<bean id = "logMethods" class = "com.MyPackage.LogMethods" lazy-init = "true" init-method="init">
    <property name = "someProperty" ref = "someBeanReference"/>
</bean>
```

And in my main method, I am getting the proxy like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
LogMethods logMethods = (LogMethods)context.getBean("proxy");
```

After executing the above code, I am not getting the log written in `before()` method of Before Calling Advice. But I am able to see the sys outs mentioned in the LogMethods class and its property reference beans also.

I want to print the before advice logs for all the methods in LogMethods and its property beans' methods (without using aspectj annotations).

I am not getting any error also. What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please don't use a `ProxyFactoryBean` anymore use the `<aop:` namespace instead, it will save you a lot of configuration. Which method are you calling how are you calling it. That part is missing.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, Thanks for the suggestion. I will try doing the same with <aop: namespace.
Regarding your question for calling methods, I am not calling any methods after getBean("proxy") right now. As you can see in the xml file, I have defined the init method for LogMethods class. I want it to log the message before calling the init method. Is that possible?

Comment: If you aren't calling methods nothing will be intercepted. At the moment of calling the init method there is no proxy yet so no interception.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I think I have understood the mistake now.